# JavaScript difference between two self invoke function?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

What is the difference between thees to approach of self invoke function is in JavaScript?

**1st variant:**

```
window.identityServer = (function () {
    const identityServer = {
        getModel () {
            const model = JSON.parse(Encoder.htmlDecode(encodedJson))

            return model
        },
    }

    return identityServer
})()
```

**2nd variant:**

```
(function () {
    const identityServer = {
        getModel () {
            const model = JSON.parse(Encoder.htmlDecode(encodedJson))

            return model
        },
    }

    return identityServer
})(window.identityServer)
```

Comment: For your second variant, you're passing `window.identityServer` as a parameter into your IIFE

Comment: @Isaac Yes, but the function does not accept any parameters, so it looks a bit pointless.

Comment: Neither of those functions is *self*-invoking. They're both *inline*-invoked, but they aren't recursive.

Comment: @Isaac if I add parametr like this ` (function (identityServer) {` difference?

Comment: @CertainPerformance  — It is completely pointless

Comment: @PalaniichukDmytro — No, because now you define a variable name for it but still don't use it.

Comment: That would throw a syntax error because it's the same as his lower `const`. Still pointless anyway, yeah.

Comment: @CertainPerformance — Oh, good point.

Comment: actually the first variant is only right way.

Answer (score 3):

The first one sets `window.identityServer` to the object created in the function.

The second one doesn't. It passes `window.identityServer` as an argument, doesn't use it, and doesn't do anything with the return value. It ends up doing nothing.